# Changing iphone camera ISO max value

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avfoundation, iso

I'm trying to change the ISO max value of my iphone during an AVCaptureSession.  I can not find an accessor to this ISO max value and its capped at 736 for the iPhone I am using.  However if I download NightCap Pro off the App Store which reports the ISO value in real time, it reports a max of 2000 when i cover up the camera lens with my thumb.  My question is:  how is this app resetting the maxISO or are they just using 2000 as an index because all maxISO values will be different from device to device?

Its odd because even if the latter is true, their picture is brighter than mine at a faster shutter speed of 1/14s while mine is 1/6s.

Comment: I've cleared out the comments here -- please keep the comments civil and on topic.

Comment: Did you try different Format, the ISO range is different in different Dimensions for iphone's back camera